# Error in sparse.model.matrix creation

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to create a `sparse.model.matrix` (from the `Matrix` package) with a formula where there is an interaction between two factors. This is fine if my input data has multiple rows but as soon as I have just one row I get the error:

`Error in model.spmatrix(t, data, transpose = transpose, drop.unused.levels = drop.unused.levels,  : cannot get a slot ("Dim") from an object of type "double"`

For example: This doesn't work:

```
f<-(mpg~as.factor(cyl)*as.factor(hp))

y<-mtcars
y$cyl<-as.factor(y$cyl)
y$hp<-as.factor(y$hp)

x<-y[1,]

myMatrix<-Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(f,x)
```

However duplicating x across two rows causes the error to disappear:

```
x<-rbind(x,x)
myMatrix<-Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(f,x)
```

I've traced the error to

`Matrix:::Csparse_vertcat` / `Matrix:::Csparse_horzcat` within `Matrix:::model.spmatrix` but am unable to work out what this function, which is written in C, is trying to do. Any ideas? Please note as far as I can determine this error only occurs when processing the matrix creation for an interaction between two factors.

Comment: try `f<-(mpg~interaction(cyl, hp))`?

Comment: Thanks @jimbou,  while`interaction(as.factor(cyl), as.factor(hp))` does kinda work the downside is it doesn't create the individual terms so cyl and hp don't enter the model separately, which means writing out the functions in a verbose manner. E.g. f<- mpg~as.factor(cyl) + as.factor(hp) + interaction(as.factor(cyl), as.factor(hp)).  Also presents challenges for interactions not present at the time of training the model but present when predicting using the model I'd still be interested to know why sparse.model.matrix fails in the above scenario.

Comment: Why would you use models with only 1 observation?

Comment: The model will go into production in an API and may only be hit by a single observation on which to predict.

Comment: If you do always `x<-rbind(x,x)`, don't you have the same model?

Comment: It's just a fictitious example. I could duplicate the row but I was hoping to understand the underlying error rather than creating a work around.